# PHP Form Not Uploading Photo to Web Folder or MSSQL Table Column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms

I have a form that is supposed to allow the user to upload an image that will have it's file saved into the folder `unitimages` and it's `filename` saved into my MSSQL table column `photo` in the table `used_trailers1`. So far, when I hit submit on my form, with the image  `4010737399_df630e8a3a_o.jpg` in the photo input. I get sent to the add.php page and the following errors are displayed:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near '`'. (severity 15) in D:\Hosting\a90\html\sales\add.php on line 25

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\Hosting\4a\html\sales\add.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(unitimages/4010737399_df630e8a3a_o.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\4a\html\sales\add.php on line 28

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Temp\php\php4D71.tmp' to 'unitimages/4010737399_df630e8a3a_o.jpg' in D:\Hosting\45a90\html\sales\add.php on line 28
Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.
```

Here is my form page's code where the image is inputted:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
 Name: <input type="text" name="title"><br> 
 E-mail: <input type="text" name = "description"><br> 
 Phone: <input type="text" name = "make"><br> 
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full PHP page code for the add.php page:

```
 <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "unitimages/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['title']; 
 $email=$_POST['description']; 
 $phone=$_POST['make']; 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 

$conn = mssql_connect('garce.com','Gdr','Rg1!');
mssql_select_db('Ggler',$conn);
if(! mssql_connect )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

 //Writes the information to the database 
 $mmssql_query = ("INSERT INTO `used_trailers1` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic')") ; 

 $Test=mssql_query($mmssql_query, $conn);

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's with the funky `` quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have 2 issues. One is the MSSQL error. The other is a permissions error.

1) Try removing the backticks around `used_trailers1`.

2) Double check that the user that your web server runs as has write permissions in that directory you are trying to move the file too.

Comment: Ah, I removed the backticks, and it removed the first errors. Now, how would I double check that?

Comment: Okay, I right clicked on the unitimages folder and clicked properties. There were 3 check boxes for user that was `read, write, and execute` and the same for group. I checked all six and the value equals 770. When I clicked okay, the server displayed `SITE CHMOD 770 unitimages  
500 'SITE CHMOD 770 unitimages': command not understood `

Comment: First run `echo exec('whoami');` from a PHP file in your browser to echo username that owns the running php/httpd process. Then compare that with the user that owns the folder. How are you running the `chmod` command? A GUI connected via FTP?

Comment: I am using coreFTP. I have the username, how do I compare the two?

Comment: They are either the same or they aren't. I never had much luck changing permissions via an FTP GUI. That's why I asked. If you have SSH access to the server or something I would recommend going that route to edit the permissions.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by compare? I'm assuming I own the folder because I created it on my own computer then transferred it to the website by FTP.

Comment: The FTP user would then own the folder. That doesn't mean that the user running the web server process has access to it unless they are one and the same. Regardless, the question remains. Is the output of `whoami` the same as the user who is listed in your FTP client?

Comment: No, they are not the same. I suppose this can only be changed through the website's cPanel, than.

Comment: Yes. Try changing the permissions via cPanel instead of changing it with the FTP client.

Comment: Cool. And for the record please sanitize your inputs.